# WSO2 ESb PayPal Intergration

Tags: paypal, wso2, wso2-esb

What is the link to the repository for adding the PayPal Business Adapter in WSO2 ESB ?

Comment: Paypal adapter implementation is done at https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/components/business-messaging/paypal/

Comment: Thanx for the link !
but when i do $ mvn  clean install in the paypal folder it gives an error 
[ERROR] Could not resolve dependencies for project org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.business.messaging.paypal.integration.core:bundle:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.core:jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of wso2-nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
Please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

http://wso2.org/library/articles/2010/06/wso2-esb-business-service-adapter-part-1-integration-paypal-ws-api

Above article provides more info. 
- Asanka